# Elasticsearch Ruby on Rails Content-Type header error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have used `elasticsearch` gem and I'm trying to run the following query

```
$es_client = Elasticsearch::Client.new  log: true
response = $es_client.search index: 'myindex',
                      body: {
                           query: { match: { title: 'test' } } } }
                         }
```

I'm getting following error:

```
[406] {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
*** Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::NotAcceptable Exception: [406] {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

I assume I need to add `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in the header. Where should I add it?

Comment: Use `gem 'searchkick'` instead of elasticsearch gem. Under the hood searchkick gem use elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also came across this issue this is due to version conflict of your library and the elasticsearch.

Make sure your are using same version of wrapper as well as elasticsearch.

Github thread for same problem.
[github thread](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/issues/350)

Comment: Updated elasticsearch gem version to 6.0.2 and it solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Wow Great Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused because of a version conflict between the version of Elasticsearch you have installed and the one that your Rails app needs. To fix this,

1. Figure out the 'elasticsearch-rails' gem you have installed (check Gemfile.lock). Each gem version corresponds to the version of Elasticsearch that it is compatible with. Read more [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails).
2. Install the required version of Elasticsearch by downloading from the corresponding webpage. For example, if you want ES 2.4 installed, use this [page](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-0-0).

I followed [this tutorial](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-mac-os-x/).